# Naming a factory kind of class which return static objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, naming-conventions, static-methods, factory-pattern

I have a dependency factory class, like

```
class DependencyFactory {
    static Dependency dependency1 = getDependency1FromSomewhere();

    static Dependency dependency2 = getDependency2FromSomewhere();

    public static Dependency getDependency(int arg1) {
        if (arg1 == 1) return dependency1;
        return dependency2;
    }
}
```

Now my confusion is on the name of the class DependencyFactory. I think this is not exactly a factory, but a decider class which return a predefined dependency based on the argument. So, is it ok to name is like DependencyFactory, or should it be something else?

Thank you. Please comment for any additional information.

Comment: How would a static factory method have access to instance variables? This code doesn't compile.

Comment: @jaco0646 that's not the point, still I've corrected that to make you feel better :)

Comment: I feel worse: static fields cannot be Autowired.  :(

Comment: @jaco0646, ok now? Can we get back to the original question if you don't mind? :) (Btw thanks for pointing that thing about static fields.)

Comment: Now it looks more like the Service Locator pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly following definition from [GoF book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

> Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class
>   to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses.

one would have to say: no - your class is not factory, because this pattern gives you a way, to **instantiate** class.

Maybe what are you looking for is a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

From my experience with design patterns often it is impossible to tell definitely which is a proper way to go, without knowing context of your system.